# Best practices sending data from local db to the remote api on restored connection?

Tags: flutter, dart, hive, bloc, dio

during some app development an essential question appeared - what is the best way to manage sending data to remote API from local db (in current case using Hive) to remote API? The one important thing, that data from local db should be sent only when connection state was down before. For example, you write a message, trying to send it but there is no connection to internet, so the data that should be sent is saved to local db. After that, the next time you open the app, it should check the connection state, check stored data in local db and then send it, and after successfull sending clear data in local db.

What is the best way it could be for dart/flutter/bloc application? At the time local data is sending via StatefulWidget onInit() state. Is there any better way/practice?